# Is there a way to clone linked user stories from a template into a new work item?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

Given a template with a bunch of linked user stories, say for onboarding new hires, when creating a new work item, e.g. a feature, using the template, unfortunately, the linked user stories in the template arent imported to the new work item as well.
Is there a workaround for this? We would have to create the user stories every time we create a new feature, and that would be exhausting, especially if the org has many new hires at once!

Capturing the feature template with linked user stories:

[image: template]

Trying to use the template, we see no user stories were replicated in the new work item (feature)!

[image: no user stories imported]

Answer (score 0):

We can use [templates to add and update work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/work-item-template?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser), with work item templates, you can quickly create work items that have pre-populated values for your team's commonly used fields. However, the child items are not contained in work item template.

If you want to link the work items, you could try to use the "Create copy of work item" then choose the "include the child work items".

[image: copy]

Comment: would the child work items be the exact same (same IDs) or would it be a copy of them?

Comment: If you copy the parent work item and include the child work items, the child work items be the same IDs.

Comment: I see, this wouldnt work for us because each new individual should have their own unique stories. I'm think a logic app may be ideal in this case, maybe it can detect when a new worm item (feature) is created that matches the title something like ”onboarding” then create and link stories to it.